# ActionBar is going up when keyboard is in use

Tags: android, window-soft-input-mode

Action Bar is going out of the screen when keyboard is in use on Edit text.

I have tried using some parameters of windowSoftInputMode on activity tag in Manifest as adjustresize, adjustPan but none of the above worked.

[image: this is the starting of app]

[image: after the edit text gets focus and keyboard is in use]

**My xml is**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

        android:layout_gravity="top"
        />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".9"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_toolbar"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_toolbar"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_toolbar"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_toolbar">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/layout1">
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <include
        layout="@layout/bottom_chat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am not able to resolve the problem

Comment: Post your layout XML.

Comment: What's in the `toolbar` layout?